# Как выделить значение в подстроке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, дата

Есть значение `10445257160000011011150000500701`

Знаю, что в данном значении последовательность `101115` это `mmddyy` (с 17 по 22 позицию всегда)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно с помощью регулярных выражений организовать проверку, что с `17` по `22` позицию будет `mmddyy`

Comment: Регулярные выражения не нужны: достаточно выдернуть из строки по фиксированным позициям три раза по две цифры, сконвертить их в числа и проверить на допустимость.

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е правильно понимаю, что регулярка здесь только все усложняет?

Comment: На мой взгляд - да. Работает медленно, выглядит как черт знает что, писать нудно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\d{16}[01]\d[0-3]\d\d\d
```

Правда полностью дату на валидность конечно не проверит. Только примерно что не может быть число `>=40` или месяц `>=20`

`^` — начало строки

`\d{16}` — 16 любых цифр

`[01]` — тут только 0 или 1

`[0-3]` — тут 0, 1, 2 или 3

Comment: здесь получается что мы проверяем все первые 16 цифр? А по сути нужно проверить только кусок "101115"

Comment: ну это просто, что бы учесть позицию - с 17. Если там могут быть любые символы то `^.{16}`

Answer (score 0):

`/^.{16}[01]\d[0-3]\d\d\d/`

На сколько возможно настолько близко выразил посредством регулярного выражения. Выражение требует строку в начале которой идут 16 любых символов (*для того чтобы искать дату начиная со следующей позиции*), далее первая цифра месяца - поэтому ограничиваемся только 0 и 1, далее вторая цифра уже без ограничений (естественно не все варианты будут правильными, например 13 месяца не существует, соответственно нужно громоздить варианты), далее первая цифра дня месяца, ограничена от 0 до 3, далее уже без ограничений вторая цифра дня месяца и двузначное значение года.

*Но ИМХО решать эту задачу регурярным выражением не есть правильно.*

Comment: 101115 - ddmmyy, где 10 - день, 11-месяц. Почему в регулярке указано только [01] ? ведь день может быть например 23 ?

Comment: В вопросе Вы спрашивали насчет mmddyy (месяц-день-год ), а не ddmmyy.

Comment: спасибо за замечание. и в правду ошибся